# Why doesn't my data display properly when I change the screen orientation?

Tags: android

I am a newbie in Android and I am currently following a tutorial on Pluralsight  while trying to reproduce the different tasks.

My question is about screen orientation, I've properly used the `onRestoreInstanceState()` and `onSaveInstanceState()` functions to store/retrieve the data when screen orientation event occurs but the content of my Button and TextView are not displayed correctly. (see images below)

Before screen rotation :

[Before entering Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEVgt.png)

[After entering Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9q1O.png)

After screen rotation :

[This is when my problem occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3J5V.png)

[Then If I touch the button again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwLmM.png)

This doesn't happen in the tutorial/video that I am following. I have thoroughly compare our two code and I can't figure out what went wrong with mine.

Here is my MainActivity.java :

```
    package com.example.ralberti.method1;

import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private EditText etName;
    private TextView txtMessage;
    private Button btnSubmit;

    // Key values
    private final String KEY_MESSAGE = "message";
    private final String KEY_BTN_TEXT = "button_text";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.i(TAG,"onCreate()");

        etName = findViewById(R.id.etName);
        txtMessage = findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                txtMessage.setText("Welcome "+ etName.getText().toString());
                btnSubmit.setText("LOGOUT");
            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState != null){
            btnSubmit.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_BTN_TEXT));
            txtMessage.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_MESSAGE));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG,"onRestoreInstanceState()");


    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
        Log.i(TAG,"onSaveInstanceState()");

        outState.putString(KEY_MESSAGE, txtMessage.getText().toString());
        outState.putString(KEY_BTN_TEXT, btnSubmit.getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.i(TAG,"onRestart()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.i(TAG,"onStart()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i(TAG,"onPause()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG,"onResume()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i(TAG,"onStop()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG,"onDestroy()");
    }

}
```

And this is activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/enter_your_name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login_message"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="#bab8b8"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have perform those tests both with the Nexus S API 28 virtual device and my own device HTC Desire 650 API 23 and the result is the same.

If someone could tell me where this problem occurs **and also explain me why** that'd be great! 
I don't just want to solve this issue but also understand what's going on. :)

Comment: Are you also changing the font color of button and textview somewhere in code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 implementations of (`onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState`)  
1st implementation:

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
}
```

2nd implementation:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {    
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
}
```

Your code includes `onSaveInstanceState` from the 2nd implementation and `onRestoreInstanceState` from the 1st. This does not work.
In `onSaveInstanceState()` replace `getString` with `putString`

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    Log.i("TAG","onSaveInstanceState()");

    outState.putString(KEY_MESSAGE, txtMessage.getText().toString());
    outState.putString(KEY_BTN_TEXT, btnSubmit.getText().toString());

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Comment: First of all you are right, this is what was written in the tutorial and I did a mistake here. Unfortunately, this didn't solve the issue and it's still not displaying the data.

Comment: Put the whole `if` statement from `onRestoreInstanceState` to `onCreate` just before `btnSubmit.setOnClickListener`

Comment: Yea I've already tried this one, didn't help.

Actually I don't think it is about the data but how it is display. (I'm a newbie but that's how I feel)

Comment: It should work either way. Is this the only code you have?

Comment: I've posted only the relevant part of Main_activity.java, this is my only activity. The point of the exercise was to give a way to deal with screen orientation but that's not working for me.
I could show you the AndroidManifest.xml, I'm not sure if it's relevant but...

Comment: I've updated my post, there is a lot of useless stuff but remember it's a tutorial for beginner

Comment: replace the `onSaveInstanceState` with the one I posted now in my answer including `@Override`

Comment: also if you have put the if statement in onCreate remove it from there

Comment: It is working now ! I don't know which part I've modified while try to apply your solution (and Tyler's as well) but now it's working properly ! Thanks to both of you

Comment: Ok I've read your edited answer and now I understand, thank you for the explanation. I used the 2nd implementation because this is the first one my IDE suggested me and I didn't pay attention nor I knew the difference between the different kind of implementation... anyway now I have a better understanding, thanks again!

Comment: How does using the two implementations affect the functionality if all the `onRestoreInstanceState` call does is call its superclass though?

Comment: it calls its superclass' s specific implementation. In the superclass there exist 2 implementations of each pair. So when you save in the 1st implementation you must restore by the 1st implementation because that bundle belongs to the 1st implementation

Answer (score 0):

Usually the state of normal views (like an `EditText`) are restored automatically on screen rotation by the base Activity code. You could try completely removing the custom code in `onSaveInstanceState` and where you apply the state in `onCreate` to see what happens.

If you want to keep it as-is, move the call to `super.onSaveInstanceState` to after you bundle your parameters, like [this example](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#java):

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    Log.i(TAG,"onSaveInstanceState()");

    outState.putString(KEY_MESSAGE, txtMessage.getText().toString());
    outState.putString(KEY_BTN_TEXT, btnSubmit.getText().toString());

    // call this after you've added your custom data
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
}
```

You can also try overriding `public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` rather than `public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState)` since you aren't using the second argument anyway.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Tyler, I called the superclass at the end of of onSaveInstanceState but it didn't work. What do you mean by "removing the custom code" ?

Comment: By custom code I meant the calls where you save and apply the text values (e.g. `btnSubmit.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_BTN_TEXT));` and  `outState.putString(KEY_BTN_TEXT, btnSubmit.getText().toString());`). Glad it's working though...